# Is there a specific name for the feet of insects?

Tags: entomology, bees

A friend and I were talking, and he asked me whether there was a name for insect feet (either in general or for specific insects). I think they are sometimes called tarsi, but I believe that's a more general term.

He is wondering about bees in particular. More specifically, he asked me, "If you were to put handcuffs on a bee, what would you call them?"

If any entomologists here have an answer, we would both appreciate it! Please rest assured that the handcuff question is purely hypothetical; no bees were harmed in the asking of this question!

Comment: Welcome A Bee. Please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance.

Comment: Did you know that you can google [insect anatomy](https://animalcorner.org/beetle-anatomy/)? On this site, we ask that people try to search for an answer themselves before asking, and to ask for clarification if there's a specific problem.